# Camel recipientList param order

Tags: url, apache-camel

I have a route defined like this:

```
from("direct:performEbayHttpCall")
.setHeader("HTTP_METHOD", constant("GET"))
.setBody(constant(null))
.log("${headers.EBAY_URL}")
.recipientList(simple("http://${headers.EBAY_URL}"))
.unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Gson);
```

When the log endpoint gets called the EBAY_URL is correct, I can copy and paste it into a browser and it works.

However when the http request is made, the url parameters are in completely the wrong order and thus causing a 500 response to be returned from the server.

Is there a way to tell camel to not mess about with the ordering of the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the query parameter ordering should NOT matter. Any HTTP server should accept query parameters in whatever order they are, eg a=1&b=2 is the same as b=2&a=1

Camel validates and normalizes the URI and the query parameters is listed in A..Z order. (nor random).

Comment: I agree that ordering shouldn't matter, eBay obviously have other ideas!